# Is it bad practice to use a global navigation provider in ionic3 with lazy loading?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using a global provider to open pages by passing the navigation controller from the page to the provider method. Is there any other way to do this better?

Main objective is not to repeat my self. Open page method I use in the globalProvider.ts is as follows. currentActive page is stored in a variable of the provider in case user logins to the app he will be redirected to the last active page (currentActive)

**globalProvider.ts**

```
  openPage(navCtrl, page, params, setActive = true) {
    this.showLoading();
    if (setActive) {
      this.currentActive = { root: page, params: params };
    } else {
      this.currentActive = { root: 'HomePage', params: null };
    }
    navCtrl.setRoot(page, params).then(res => {
      if (!res) {
        this.showError('Please login to view page!');
        navCtrl.setRoot('LoginPage', {
          activePage: this.currentActive.root
        }).then(res => {
          this.hideLoading();
        }).catch(err => {
          this.hideLoading();
        });
      }
      this.hideLoading();

    }).catch(error => {
      this.hideLoading();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything bad with this practice. I also do similar logic to avoid repeating the show loading and hide loading logic in every page.

However I also keep **one more parameter**, to help me decide if the page should be set as root or should be pushed on current stack.

This also helps me to track page views for analytics from a central place.

Comment: I do have a separate function for push methods because I don't set the active parameter for pushed pages. Having a parameter for it in my case doesn't reduce much code lines and so I used another method for it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you :)